# Auto close of "fs.createWriteStream()" to avoid potential memory leak

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io, memory-leaks, node.js-fs

To upload a file locally I'm using the following code:

```js
import {pipeline} from "stream";
import {promisify} from "util";

const asyncPipeline = promisify(pipeline);

await asyncPipeline(
    fileData.fileStream,
    fs.createWriteStream(
        path.join(assetsPath, fileName),
        {

            flags: "wx"
        }
    )
);
```

My questions:

1. It does work but I'm not sure if I need to do something extra, for instance, to close a stream manually, or the default `true`-value of `autoClose` does it for me automatically?
2. How can I ensure that the `WriteStream` is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the pipeline option `autoClose`'s default value of `true` will handle the closing of the stream. Whether the pipeline fails or succeeds, you can rest assured that the file descriptor will automatically be closed.

For more information on options and error handling, see the [pipeline documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_source_transforms_destination_callback).